# How can I send a div via node js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas

**Context:** *I am creating a web app where I can draw on the canvas, save that as an image, and send it to another client via Node.*

**What works:**

- Drawing (on either client. It is updated in real time).
- Saving canvas as a Uint8Array
- Saving canvas as an img div w/ base64 encoded image

**Where I'm stuck:**

I can't seem to pipe the finished image to other clients. I'm able to save the canvas in a variety of ways, but not sure of how to get it across.

**How I'm sending it to the node server as a div:**

```
   byId('sendHTML').onclick = SendImageHTML;  
   function SendImageHTML() {    
        var imageHTML = convertCanvasToImage(canvas); 
        socket.emit('SendImageHTML', imageHTML);
        // EMITS: <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVB9023423523345346....."
   }
```

**Sending as a Uint8Array:**

```
  /**
   * Converts canvas to bytes & emits web socket message
   * @return {Uint8Array} Bytes from canvas 
   */     
  byId('defImgBinary').onclick = DefineImageBinary;  
  function DefineImageBinary() {
        var image  = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(image.data.length);
        var bytes  = new Uint8Array(buffer);

        for (var i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
            bytes[i] = image.data[i];
        }

        socket.emit('defImgBinary', bytes);
        // EMITS: [24, 24, 29, 255, 24, 24, 29, 255, 24, 24.......]

  }
```

---

And here is my server code:

```
socket.on('SendImageHTML', function (html) {
    console.log("SendImageHTML called: ");
    log(html);
    // RETURNS:
    // SendImageHTML called:
    // {} 
});




socket.on('defImgBinary', function (bytes) {
    log("defImgBinary called: ");
    log(bytes);
    // RETURNS:
    // defImgBinary called:
    // '53721': 220,
    // '53722': 219,
    // '53723': 255,
    // '53724': 229,
});
```

**What I need help with:**

*What do I do with it from there? How do I actually display this as an image on the other clients?*

Comment: Just `socket.broadcast.emit` that data from the server. It will send it to [all connected sockets except the one that sent the image data](http://socket.io/docs/#broadcasting-messages). Since its an `<img>` html you're sending, the clients can just add it to the DOM and it will be displayed on the next render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would that be satisfactory for you, if you'd use `getDataURL()` from the Canvas API and then send a base64 encoded image or a rendered DOM element?

## On the client side:

You can obtain base64-encoded data from your canvas via [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) . That will result in a String starting with `data:image/png;base64...`, just as in your code sample.

When you obtain the string, you can either send it directly to the server as a String, or render it into an Image element:

```
var image = new Image(width, height);
image.src = myBase64String;

image.addEventListener('load', function () { /* NOTE On image loaded */ });
```

If you want to send a rendered DOM Element to the server, you will probably find `Element.outerHTML` very useful - this property will return an exact string representation of the element (ex. `"<img src="data:image/png;base64..." width="256" height="256" />"`).

## On the server side:

In both cases, you can simply send the data through to the other clients via their sockets.

## On the other clients' side:

If you send a simple base64 encoded string, it can be easily rendered using an `Image` element:

```
var image = new Image(256, 256);
image.src = receivedBase64String;

image.addEventListener('load', function () { 
  document.appendChild(image);
});
```

If you send an already rendered element, you can put it into the DOM structure using `document.createElement`:

```
var image = document.createElement('div'); // NOTE Create a 'host' element
image.innerHTML = receivedRenderedElementString;

document.appendChild(image);
```

## Example:

Please see the code attached below for a working example.

Client side:

```
<title>
  Canvas Sample
</title>
<p>
  <canvas id="sample-canvas" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
</p>
<p>
  <button id="send-canvas">
    Send canvas
  </button>
  <label for="send-as-div">
    <input type="checkbox" id="send-as-div">
      Send as div
    </input>
  </label>
</p>
<p id="output-console"></p>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
  // NOTE Simple IO console element for socket communication
  let outputConsole = document.querySelector('#output-console');
  let printToConsole = (text = '') => {
    outputConsole.innerHTML += text + '<br/>';
  };
  let renderToConsole = (element) => {
    outputConsole.appendChild(element);
    outputConsole.innerHTML += '<br/>';
  };

  // NOTE Load image (random cat image)
  let image = new Image(250, 250);
  image.src = 'http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&size=small';
  printToConsole('Image loading.');

  // NOTE Setup canvas
  // Render the cat image when it is loaded.
  let canvas = document.querySelector('#sample-canvas');
  let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  image.addEventListener('load', () => {
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    printToConsole('Image loaded.');
  });

  image.addEventListener('error', (error) => {
    printToConsole('Image error.' + JSON.strinfify(error));
  });

  // NOTE Setup a websocket
  // Socket will allow to send 'img' message with either a base64 encoded
  // image data, or a rendered HTML Image element.
  let socket = io('ws://localhost:8080/');

  socket.on('error', (error) => {
    printToConsole('Socket error.' + JSON.stringify(error));
  });

  socket.on('img', (image) => {
    let renderedImage = null;

    if (image.indexOf('data:image/') === 0) {

      // NOTE If we receive a base64 image, we render it as an Image
      renderedImage = new Image(250, 250);
      renderedImage.src = image;
    } else {

      // NOTE If we receive a rendered <img> element, we render it directly
      // via document.createElement
      renderedImage = document.createElement('div');
      renderedImage.innerHTML = image;
    }

    printToConsole('Received image.');
    renderToConsole(renderedImage);
  });

  // NOTE Setup button
  let sendButton = document.querySelector('#send-canvas');

  sendButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let encodedCanvas = canvas.toDataURL();
    let sendAsDiv = document.querySelector('#send-as-div').checked;
    let payload = null;

    if (sendAsDiv) {
      let imageElement = new Image(250, 250);
      imageElement.src = encodedCanvas;

      payload = imageElement.outerHTML;
    } else {
      payload = encodedCanvas;
    }

    socket.emit('img', payload);

    printToConsole('Image sent.');
  });
</script>
```

Server side (requires `npm install -D express socket.io`):

```
'use strict';

let express = require('express');
let http = require('http');
let socketIo = require('socket.io');

// NOTE Setup server
let httpServer = http.createServer(express());
let socketServer = socketIo(httpServer);
let sockets = [];
let port = 8080;

httpServer.listen(port);

// NOTE Setup socket listener

socketServer.on('connection', (socket) => {
  sockets.push(socket);

  let socketId = sockets.length;

  socket.on('img', (payload) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('img', payload);
  });
});
```

Let me know if that solves your issue

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning base64 representation of the image for connected clients to consume.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I was making this way more complicated than it needed to be. Thanks for the thorough response, and for offering two solutions!